# Python unchecking checkbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I was messing around a little bit with python. I had an idea and wanted to make a program. Now instead of making it go to a command prompt, I wanted to make a simple GUI, since I never really made those myself.
Now I was trying around a little bit and for some reason, whenever I check my checkbox, it does do what it should do, but it will not appear to be checked. I spent a good amount googling why this is happening, but I usually end up at a site with code that is beyond my understanding.
Does anyone know to to fix this?
And maybe make checking and unchecking the checkbox do different things in not too complicated code?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import time

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")
root.title("Login")


def checkbutton(event):
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Keep me logged in','I`ll remeber it!')
    print("test")

def showCredentials(event):
    USERNAME = entryUsername.get()
    PASSWORD = entryPassword.get()
    print(USERNAME)
    print(PASSWORD)

def deleteText(event):
    testLabel.destroy()
    print("Done!")


username = Label(root, text="Username")
password = Label(root, text="Password")
username.grid(row=0,column=0)
password.grid(row=1,column=0)


entryUsername = Entry(root)
entryPassword = Entry(root)
entryUsername.grid(row=0,column=1)
entryPassword.grid(row=1,column=1)

keepMeLoggedIn = Checkbutton(root,text="Keep me logged in")
keepMeLoggedIn.bind("<Button-1>", checkbutton)
keepMeLoggedIn.grid(columnspan=2,sticky=E)

testButton = Button(root, text="Print credentials")
testButton.bind("<Button-1>", showCredentials)
testButton.grid(row=3, column=1)


# **** TEST ****

testLabel = Label(root, text="test")
testLabel.grid(row=4, column=1)
testButton1 = Button(root,text="delete text")
testButton1.bind("<Button-1>", deleteText)
testButton1.grid(row=4, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: A Tkinter `Checkbutton` (or `Radiobutton`) must be associated with a Tkinter Var (typically an instance of `IntVar` or `StringVar`) via its `variable=` option - that's what actually stores its state.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by the `bind` of `keepMeLoggedIn`

replace you `keepMeLoggedIn` code with this,

```
keepMeLoggedIn = Checkbutton(root,text="Keep me logged in",command=checkbutton1)
#keepMeLoggedIn.bind("<Button-1>", checkbutton)
keepMeLoggedIn.grid(columnspan=2,sticky=E)
```

and replace your `checkbutton()` method to,

```
def checkbutton1():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Keep me logged in','I`ll remeber it!')
    print("test")
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: command attribute specifies the function to call when a button is clicked!. In your case i tried to add a BooleanVar to checkbutton, but it does not works as specified, it remains checked all the time.

Comment: @PrathameshJadhav: `BooleanVar` does work; if it didn't work, you didn't use it correctly.